# How to call block class function from phtml file

Tags: php, magento

I have block class

```
    class GauravKhatri_BestSeller_Block_Index extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

public function getBestsellerProducts()
{       
//Here is my code
}
}
```

I have  bestseller.phtml file.
I want to get result of that function on phtml file.

Can anyone help me how to do it.

Comment: have you created the layout xml file.?

Answer (score 1):

If this template file "bestseller.phtml" is directly associated with your block. like below example:

```
<block type="bestSeller/index" name="bestseller" template="bestseller.phtml "/>
```

then you can access all the functions of this block class `GauravKhatri_BestSeller_Block_Index` in associated template using `$this`. like example:

```
$this->getBestsellerProducts();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call block in template directly

```
$bestseller = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('bestSeller/index');
$bestseller->getBestsellerProducts();
```